# How do you format request header with php's stream_context_create()?

Tags: php, http-headers, file-get-contents

I need help defining my $opts variable for a file_get_contents requests.

To do that you're supposed to define your context like so:

```
    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
      )
    );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

How can I format the following headers into the $opt's variable above?

```
GET /oncorev2/DetailTop.aspx?ref= HTTP/1.1
Host: subdomain.domain.org
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.3215.75 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://subdomain.domain.org/oncorev2/ShowDetails.aspx?CFN=98664975
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wptjainh1n40er45inkk3v45; OnCoreWeb=AutoLoadImages=-1&ImageViewer=2&DefaultNumberOfRows=10
```

I've tried a few different ways and they're all wrong. This is an example of one that I've tried.

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"GET /oncorev2/DetailTop.aspx?ref= HTTP/1.1
Host: subdomain.domain.org
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.3215.75 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://subdomain.domain.org/oncorev2/ShowDetails.aspx?CFN=104525097
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=lrv3rfjl1ay0aj45v33s0ozm;OnCoreWeb=AutoLoadImages=-1&ImageViewer=2&DefaultNumberOfRows=10"
  ));
```

Thanks

REVISION:
As suggested in the comment I've now also tried

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>array("Host: subdomain.domain.org",
"Connection: keep-alive",
"Cache-Control: max-age=0",
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.3215.75 Safari/537.36",
"Referer: https://subdomain.domain.org/oncorev2/ShowDetails.aspx?CFN=104525097",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch",
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n",
"Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=lrv3rfjl1ay0aj45v33s0ozm;OnCoreWeb=AutoLoadImages=-1&ImageViewer=2&DefaultNumberOfRows=10")
  ));
```

Comment: Just use an array e.g. `'header'=> array("Accept-language: en", "Cookie: foo=bar")`

Comment: Forgive me if I seem dumb. I'm using arrays. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Your header element is currently a single string. Instead of `'header'=>'header1' . 'header2'`, convert the element to an array as above

Comment: I probably don't understand you. I showed my understanding of what you're saying in the revision now reflected in my post. It doesn't work, but tell me if I'm getting close.